# Wordpress Elementor Header issue

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am new to elementor, and by watching youtube created first website http://itz4u.in/itz4u/ in wordpress in mochahost.com. It is working fine but I can not remove header from this page.

Comment: Do you have any updates ?

Comment: Hi any updates ? Pl help

Comment: Hi site url is in.itz4u.in, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To remove the header in a page, open the page with Elementor Editor.

Click on page settings (little gear icon) on the left bottom of screen.

In page layout, select CANVAS.

This will eliminate header and footer on the page.

If you need to remove only the header, you can create a empty Header template and define that as header. This way the footer will be visible and header invisible. In this case remember to leave the page layout as DEFAULT

Answer (score 0):

If you create a header in Template then easily you can delete else open header in elementor editor, a select section of header, go to advanced settings then click on responsive, In responsive there are 3 options of visibility you can make enabled that option where you want to hide or remove.